# Can't load embedding from persistent directory

Tags: openai-api, embedding, langchain

I'm reading .txt files, creating embeddings and storing them in a folder.
But when I try to load them I´m not getting the embeddings:

```
persist_directory = "embeddings_db"
...
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=100, )
texts = text_splitter.split_documents( documents )
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, model="text-embedding-3-large")
docsearch = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings, persist_directory=persist_directory)
docsearch.persist()
```

If at this point if I try to print the ids I get the list:

```
print(docsearch.get()["ids"])
```

But later if I try to load the embeddings from the same folder I not getting docs:

```
docsearch = None
....
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, model="text-embedding-3-large")
docsearch = Chroma(persist_directory, embedding_function=embeddings ) #persist_directory
llm = OpenAI(temperature=0, openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY )
chain = load_qa_chain(llm, chain_type="stuff")
```

Below code return an empty list:

```
print(docsearch.get()["ids"])
```